# My keyboard layout changes to Qwerty while there is no Qwerty configured?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, language-bar

I have a problem with my keyboard or software, see the following pictures.

[image]

[image]

As you can see there is only an Azerty keyboard layout configured, while my keyboard's setting keeps changing to the Qwerty keyboard layout. Can somebody help me with this? It is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a badly written mouse software that had an interesting issue. Whenever I clicked in a specific edit field it would switch to English keyboard layout even though none were configured.

The most common cause of the issue you describe is to accidentally press alt+shift to change the languages but that doesn't work in your case when only one language is configured.

I would try to pinpoint when it happens, is it in a specific application? maybe even a specific edit field or dialog box in an application? Also you should check for any keyboard software you have installed and try to disable or uninstall that and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: It happens in many of the applications (so will be a main problem).